# user is able to type alpha characters in mobile , but in laptop is working fine

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Here is code sample in Reactjs.
Is there problem with `event.preventDefault();` ?
What should I try
please help me.

```
<Select 
    options={options}
    components={{ DropdownIndicator, ValueContainer,IndicatorSeparator:() => null }}
    styles={styles}
    placeholder={placeholder}
    onChange={(e)=> {onChange(e.value)}}
    value={value}
    defaultValue={defaultValue}
    onKeyDown={(event) => {
        if (!/[0-9]/.test(event.key) && event.key !== 'Backspace') {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      }}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used `onInputChange`

```
<Select 
    options={options}
    components={{ DropdownIndicator, ValueContainer,IndicatorSeparator:() => null }}
    styles={styles}
    placeholder={placeholder}
    onChange={(e)=> {onChange(e.value)}}
    value={value}
    defaultValue={defaultValue}
    onInputChange={(val) => {
        return isNaN(val) ? '' : val; // only take number
    }}
```